# Auto refresh the page in Editform.aspx with ID query string param with updated list item value in Presaveitem()

Tags: sharepoint-online, edit-form, presaveaction

am having an `editform.aspx` page in my SPO site. am using `presaveitem()` in my content editor web part to perform validation and etc after completion of calling of `presaveitem()`, i ant to stay on the same page , ie, i wanna stay  like : `https://mycustomersposite/msite/lists/splist1/editform.aspx?ID=425` with the same ID, after refreshing the page automatically.

```
 function Presaveitem()
 {  
 //perform validation .. etc 

   alert("Item is updated successfully on 11/05 monday");
   alert('reloading the page');
    window.location.reload();

return true;
}
```

The problem am facing is, after click on the save button, its automatically redirecting to the `AllItems.aspx` page always.  what my understanding is if i call just before closing of Presaveitem() fun.call
        `window.location.reload();` , it will reload the page with the latest updates happened to the list items id , mentioned in the ?ID=mylistitemidnumber
. 
How to stop redirecting to the allitems.aspx page from editform?
is it possible to add a ?source param in the URL, ( inject it on page load) automatically/programmatically?

Comment: First of all, the meaning of presaveitem is that it is called before saving the item. Why would you write saving functionality inside presaveitem? There are multiple ways to achieve it. Do you have the freedom to edit the forms in designer?

Comment: @harshal, if i create a new custom form in SP designer, what i have observed that, i am unable to add a content editor wbe part in that custom form. its showing weird behaviour.  so, i thought of using the existing,default newform, editform pages

Comment: "there are multiple ways to achieve it." --> can you please elaborate it and what are the ways to achieve it. help is appreciated!

Comment: If you sant to use the default form, then you can override the submit button action and redirect after saving.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Please find the screenshot of edit page with script editor web part and after addming the web part how your edit form URL looks like]This block of code helped me in the past. Add a script editor on the edit form and paste the code in the script editor web part.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title",window.location.href+"?Source=http://YourPageURL");
});
</script>
```

Comment: are you saying that, just before closing the presaveitem(), i dont need to reload the page --> no need to call .reload()??

Comment: After the source attribute, use edit form url, it will reload the current page.
you should use exact the following line of code.
**window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", window.location.href+"?Source="+window.location.href);**

Comment: after adding your code, it seems, the values are not getting saved into the splist. it loaded with the old values. i  think, its not committing in the DB.

Comment: I tried it with my splist and it worked well for me please see the screenshot attached